# Highlight previous week on calendar

Tags: php, date

I have this calendar with the current date highlighted. I would like to highlight the previous week, today is 30/03/2015 so the dates highlighted would be from 23 to 29. The script works fine if I choose dates from the first column (Mon) but fails when I'm clicking on let's say 26, I get dates from 19 to 25 instead of 16 to 22. Any thoughts?

```
if(isset($_GET['day'])) {

  for ($i = -7; $i < 0; $i++) {
    print date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-','/', $_GET['day'])) + $i * 86400) . "<br />";
  }
}
```

And here's the calendar
[image: Calendar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd figure out the first Monday of the week you're after then output the dates from there. Your script currently doesn't account for where in the week you are it just outputs the previous 7 days.

```
if(!empty($_GET['day'])){
    $int = strtotime($_GET['day']);
    $firstmonday = strtotime('monday last week', $int);
    for($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) {
        echo date('Y-m-d', $firstmonday + (86400 * $i)) . "<br />";
    }
}
```

Since sunday is a special case lets check if the requested date is one.

```
if(!empty($_GET['day'])){
    $int = strtotime($_GET['day']);
    $interval = (date('N', $int) == 7) ? '-2 week' : '-1 week';
    $firstmonday = strtotime($interval, $int);
    for($i = 1; $i < 8; $i++) {
        echo date('Y-m-d', $firstmonday + (86400 * $i)) . "<br />";
    }
}
```

Comment: Everything is working except when I'm choosing dates from Sunday. If 22 is clicked the numbers I get are from 16 to 22 instead of 9 to 15, why is that?

Comment: The previous Monday from the 22nd was the 17th, so 16-22 is what I'd expect. You want 2 weeks ago if it is a Sunday though it sounds like, is that right?

Comment: Yes, so I should be strtotime('monday last 2 weeks', $int);?

Comment: Nope because you want all the other days to still process as one week (right?). I'll make an update.

Comment: Now if 22 is clicked, it will show from 17 to 23 instead of 9 to 15. I will have to add some style to the row that holds the previous week. A week starts on Monday and ends on Sunday. For example today is 2015-03-30, then the calendar would display from 23 to 29. Makes sense?

Comment: I'm not seeing the 17 to 23 when testing '2015-03-22', you're using the second chunk of code, right?

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($_GET['day'])) {
  $shift = (intval(date('w', strtotime($_GET['day']))) - 1)%7; 
  // Numeric representation of the day of the week, 0 for sunday -> need to sub 1 day
  for ($i = -7; $i < 0; $i++) {
    print date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-','/', $_GET['day'])) + ($i - $shift) * 86400) . "<br />";
  }
}
```

It should work in your case. 
The basic idea is to get numeric representation of day of the week (sunday => 0) and subtract them from current date.